# Xcode "Run Script" === command not found

Tags: xcode, macos, build

I have a script that is run as part of my build process which uses DMGCanvas to create a finished DMG file with my app on it. The file at:

```
"$SRCROOT/diskimage/dmgcanvas"
```

is a symbolic link to the dmgcanvas tool which is embedded in the DMGCanvas.app package in the Applications folder.

Line 92:
`"$SRCROOT/diskimage/dmgcanvas" "$SRCROOT/diskimage/MyApp.dmgCanvas" "$SRCROOT/Build/Products/Release/myapp.dmg" -volumeName MyApp -setFilePath MyApp.app "$SRCROOT/Build/Products/Release/MyApp.app"`

This works correctly and builds a proper DMG file, but in the Xcode build results I see:

```
/Volumes/Projects/MyApp/scripts/PackageApp.sh: line 92: ===: command not found
```

Why is it showing this error when the command executed correctly?

Note that for some reason the StackOverflow site is not showing the pointy single quotes around the command (the character under the tilde key).

Comment: Can you show us what is line 92 in your script?

Comment: Line 92 is what I wrote above in the 3-line block. The command runs fine since a dmg is correctly produced. I have edited it for clarity.

Comment: dmgcanvas is the command and the dmgcanvas tool is located at "$SRCROOT/diskimage/dmgcanvas"